# Wordpress Disable Page if user not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page 'account' where I want users to be able to edit their profile.

But how do I disable the page for users who are not logged in?
Maybe with: !is_user_logged_in ?

They should not be able to access the page. Maybe get redirected to login page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this code in your Function.php file.
[using `template_redirect` action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

```
function template_redirect_fn()
{
    if(is_page (Page ID, title, slug of account page ) && !is_user_logged_in ())
    {
        $loginUrl = home_url('/login-page/');
        wp_redirect($loginUrl);
         exit(); 
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_fn' );
```

[is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) is check page is account [you can pass the account page id or page title or page slug ]

[is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) is check user is login or not return  (bool) True if user is logged in, false if not logged in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfect. I tweaked it a little:
$loginUrl = wp_login_url();
So the user gets forced to the login page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this flowing way.

```
if( !is_user_logged_in ) {
   $loginUrl = home_url('/login-page/');
   echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
}
```

Comment: You can also use `wp_get_current_user();` which will return the user object and the ID will be 0 if the user is not logged in.